# Corona masking, how to add 2 or more masks to display group

Tags: lua, coronasdk, mask, displayobject

Hy all, i'm develope 1 little game both for android and iOS in Corona.

I need to set a mask to an image when users touch the group.
Here is my code:

```
   local function eat( event )
      if event.phase == "began" the

        local mask = graphics.newMask( "file/mask.png" )
        local playSound = audio.play( biteSound )

        onDishGroup:setMask( mask )
        onDishGroup.maskX= event.x
        onDishGroup.maskY = event.y

    return true
end
```

The question is, how can i add multiple mask to that group ? 
Its work well, but this will set only 1 mask at a time, the old will remove or it will be just moving to the new  x y.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add multiple masks like that...

But you can put several groups one inside the other and add mask to them... Yes it is a ugly hack but...

Comment: thx, btw dosn't work whit my code... pls check where i'm wrong

Comment: When i make a display group as an array and after onTouch i add the previous group to the new 1, after touche event the 1st bakcground will die.
is realy when i add an object to 2 more displaygroup that will die ?